System Shutdown after new install [Ubuntu 24.04.1]
I did a new clean install to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and whipped my SSD. When I Boot to my System and let it run after Boot (running only Firefox) the System shuts down after 45-58 minutes.
I didn't installed other Apps just using Ubuntu out of the box.. I run before Ubuntu 22 LTS with no issues.
I used Wayland and non Wayland on login...
This are my specs:
Machine      -  TUXEDO InfinityBook Pro Gen8 (MK2) Stan
Graphic Card -  NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3050 6GB Laptop GPU
Kernel       -  6.8.0-44-generic
Distro       -  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Packages     -  1612 (dpkg), 14 (snap)
Terminal     -  gnome-terminal
Shell        -  bash
CPU          -  13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700H (20)
Resolution   -  2880x1800
Memory       -  64 GB

Edit your question: Did it warn you that it was shutting down? Did it shut down cleanly? Did it return to the boot screen with the manufacturer logo? Or did it suddenly poweroff in the middle of your work without warning? If the latter, then you have a hardware fault, not an Ubuntu fault.

Your output shows that you are using the Firefox snap (* 13 others). Snaps are isolated by design, with only specific connections to the rest of the system permitted. The Firefox snap is allowed to see your /home directory, but nothing else. Your output shows repeated attempted access to areas outside of this: - eg: - path="/org/freedesktop/timedate1", path="/org/freedesktop/login1", exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" ... etc. Does this still fail if you don't run any snaps? As an experiment try running with a selection of Deb apps and report back results by appending to your question.

@user535733 It didn't warn me it shutdown in middle of the work... I would say , yes it was shutting down clean.. I could press the Powerbutton afterwards and the Manufactor Logo came and Loginscreen and everything.. Everything was fine just after some running time it was shutting down again nothing odd when running...

@david thx for analyzing... just to be more clear what i did after this post... i tried to run dwm and i had some errors while compiling about the x11 lib... So i installed build-essential after that i had still some x11lib errors so i installed libx11-dev after that i still had some errors about x11 but couldn't solve it so one day passed !still with crashes! and the next day i installed as last this xft and afterthat everything worked... so that's why i thought it could be maybe an x11 issue...

i installed this ->
sudo apt install build-essential libx11-dev libxinerama-dev libxft-dev
...... and downloaded and installed this xft pkg ->
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xft/2.3.6-1build1
